# A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is wrong with this statement?

```
ALTER Function [InvestmentReturn].[getSecurityMinLowForPeriod](@securityid int,
    @start datetime,
    @end datetime)
returns xml
begin

declare @results varchar(500)
declare @low int
declare @adjustedLow int
declare @day varchar(10)

if @end is null
begin
    set @end = getdate()
end
set @adjustedLow = (select min(adjLow) 
                        from (
                            select Low * [InvestmentReturn].[fn_getCorporateActionSplitFactor](isq.securityid, @start, convert(varchar,day, 111)) as adjLow 
                            from 
                                securityquote isq
                            where isq.securityid = @securityid and isq.day >= convert(varchar(10), @start, 111) and convert(varchar(10), @end, 111) >= isq.day
                            and low != -1 
                            ) as x)
select 
    top 1 @low = low
    , @day = day
    , @adjustedLow
--select high
from 
    securityquote sq
where 
    day >= convert(varchar(10), @start, 111) and convert(varchar(10), @end, 111) >= day
    and securityid = @securityid and low != -1
order by low asc

    set @results=  '<results type="debug_min">'
    set @results = @results + '<periodStart>' + coalesce(cast(@start as varchar(20)), 'NULL') + '</periodStart>' 
    set @results = @results + '<periodEnd>' + coalesce(cast(@end  as varchar(20)), 'NULL') + '</periodEnd>' 
    set @results = @results + '<securityID>' + coalesce(cast(@securityID as varchar(10)), 'NULL') + '</securityID>'
    set @results = @results + '<periodMin>' + coalesce(cast(@low as varchar(10)), '-11111') + '</periodMin>'
    set @results = @results + '<coraxAdjustedPeriodMin>' + coalesce(cast(@adjustedLow as varchar(10)), '-11111') + '</coraxAdjustedPeriodMin>'
    set @results = @results + '<dayMinOcurred>' + coalesce(@day, 'NULL') + '</dayMinOcurred>'
    set @results = @results + '</results>'

return @results
```

Just to explain the answer (after getting where the error was caused), I simply removed @adjustedLow from the second select statement.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Column values from the SELECT statement are assigned into `@low` and  `@day` local variables; the `@adjustedLow` value is not assigned into any variable and it causes the problem:

The problem is here:

```
select 
    top 1 @low = low
    , @day = day
    , @adjustedLow  -- causes error!
--select high
from 
    securityquote sq
...
```

Detailed explanation and workaround: [SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 141 - A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-141.aspx)

Comment: Well, the workaround provided don't let you do both getting the result set and pushing one of the values to a variable. So basically, if you need to do this (not the case here, I know), then you have to write and run the query twice :(

Answer (score 16):

You cannot use a select statement that assigns values to variables to also return data to the user
The below code will work fine, because i have declared 1 local variable and that variable is used in select statement.

```
 Begin
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(max)
    select @name=PolicyHolderName from Table
    select @name
    END
```

The below code will throw error "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable 
must not be combined with data-retrieval operations" Because we are retriving data(PolicyHolderAddress) from table, but error says data-retrieval operation is not allowed when you use some local variable as part of select statement.

```
 Begin
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(max)
    select 
       @name = PolicyHolderName,
       PolicyHolderAddress 
    from Table
 END
```

The the above code can be corrected like below,

```
Begin
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @address varchar(100)
    select 
       @name = PolicyHolderName,
       @address = PolicyHolderAddress 
    from Table
END
```

So either remove the data-retrieval operation or add extra local variable. This will resolve the error.

Comment: @Matas I am trying to get the shortest city string along with its length, so i tried below
`SELECT TOP 1 @SHORTEST_CITY = S.CITY,   LEN(S.CITY) AS LENGTH FROM STATION S ORDER BY LENGTH DESC; `. 
But i get `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.` . I intend to sort by length not alphabetically. Any thoughts on it ?

Comment: @SanKrish can you try this, DECLARE SHORTEST_CITY nvarchar(max)
DECLARE LENGTH varchar(100)
SELECT TOP 1 SHORTEST_CITY=S.CITY, LENGTH =LEN(S.CITY) FROM STATION S  ORDER BY LEN(S.CITY) DESC;
select SHORTEST_CITY
select LENGTH

Answer (score -8):

```
declare @cur cursor
declare @idx int       
declare @Approval_No varchar(50) 

declare @ReqNo varchar(100)
declare @M_Id  varchar(100)
declare @Mail_ID varchar(100)
declare @temp  table
(
val varchar(100)
)
declare @temp2  table
(
appno varchar(100),
mailid varchar(100),
userod varchar(100)
)


    declare @slice varchar(8000)       
    declare @String varchar(100)
    --set @String = '1200096,1200095,1200094,1200093,1200092,1200092'
set @String = '20131'


    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(',',@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String

            --select @slice       
            insert into @temp values(@slice)
        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break


    end
    -- select distinct(val) from @temp


SET @cur = CURSOR FOR select distinct(val) from @temp


--open cursor    
OPEN @cur    
--fetchng id into variable    
FETCH NEXT    
    FROM @cur into @Approval_No 

      --
    --loop still the end    
     while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN   


select distinct(Approval_Sr_No) as asd, @ReqNo=Approval_Sr_No,@M_Id=AM_ID,@Mail_ID=Mail_ID from WFMS_PRAO,WFMS_USERMASTER where  WFMS_PRAO.AM_ID=WFMS_USERMASTER.User_ID
and Approval_Sr_No=@Approval_No

   insert into @temp2 values(@ReqNo,@M_Id,@Mail_ID)  

FETCH NEXT    
      FROM @cur into @Approval_No    
 end  
    --close cursor    
    CLOSE @cur    

select * from @tem
```