# Select and assign to variable in one statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to display the results of a query, and I'd like to capture a column's value at the same time. The `FROM` and `WHERE` are the same in both queries. Can I do both in one query, or is it easier/better to just do the query twice, like this?

```
DECLARE @fooId INT

SET @fooId = (SELECT FooId FROM Bar WHERE SnuhId = 5)

SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE SnuhId = 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it has to be done in two operations.

Test:

```
DECLARE @VAR DATETIME
SELECT @VAR=GETDATE(), GETDATE()
```

Yields error message 141.

[Here's another SO post on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608140/a-select-statement-that-assigns-a-value-to-a-variable-must-not-be-combined-with)

Answer (score 3):

If you try to do it in one query, you will get an error msg - `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`

To avoid this, the possibilities are

1) Make sure that all columns are assigned to a local variable. Ex

```
DECLARE @fooId INT
DECLARE @barId INT

SELECT @fooId = FooId, @barId = BarId FROM Bar WHERE SnuhId = 5
```

2) simply remove '*' from the SELECT statement

```
SELECT @fooId = FooId, BarId FROM Bar WHERE SnuhId = 5 //remove BarId column from this query
```

3) If you really need to do both, meaning to assign the value to local variables and to return the columns as a result set, you have to do it in 2 steps instead of combining them into one SELECT statement.

Comment: +1 for the other possible options, even though they don't work for me. The real answer appears to be that you just can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to reduce one line:

```
DECLARE @fooI INT
SET @fooId = (SELECT FooId FROM Bar WHERE SnuhId = 5)
SELECT @fooId as [FooId]
```

It will reduce unnecessary replication of your query.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is accurate, however he wants * back from the table, not just the assigned id value.