# SQL Server - Adding up variables combined with data-retrieval operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

When I run the code below I get this error:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.

Please see my code below:

```
DECLARE @M1 float
DECLARE @M2 float
declare @M3 float
DECLARE @M4 float
DECLARE @M5 float
DECLARE @M6 float
DECLARE @M7 float
DECLARE @M8 float
DECLARE @M9 float
DECLARE @M10 float
DECLARE @M11 float
DECLARE @M12 float
declare @theSum float

set @M1 = 0
set @m2 = 1954286
set @M3 = 1954286
set @M4 = 0
set @M5 = 0
set @M6 = 0
set @M7 = 0
set @M8 = 0
set @M9 = -11725714
set @M10 = 1954286
set @M11 = 1954286
set @theSum = @M1+@M2+@M4+@M5+@M6+@M7+@M8+@M9+@M10+@M11+@M12

SELECT  @theSum,

        @M3   = case 
                --   when M3 = 0 then 0
                     when @M1+@M2+@M4+@M5+@M6+@M7+@M8+@M9+@M10+@M11+@M12 != 0 then @M3-@M2 -- mvc
                else
                    case when @M2 != 0 then @m3-@m2
                         when @M1 != 0 then @m3-@m1
                         when @M12 != 0 then @m3-@m12
                         when @M11 != 0 then @m3-@m11
                         when @M10 != 0 then @m3-@m10
                         when @M9 != 0 then @m3-@m9
                         when @M8 != 0 then @m3-@m8
                         when @M7 != 0 then @m3-@m7
                         when @M6 != 0 then @m3-@m6
                         when @M5 != 0 then @m3-@m5
                         when @M4 != 0 then @m3-@m4

                         else              @m3
                    end 
                end
```

It's not necessary to explain what I need to achieve, all I want is an example where you can assign values to variables and then use them in a case statement like in the example above. Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608140/a-select-statement-that-assigns-a-value-to-a-variable-must-not-be-combined-with)

Comment: This kind of error occurs when you are assigning the column values from a SELECT statement into local variables but not all columns are assigned to a corresponding local variable.  refer this link:  http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-141.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty clear: a query *either* assigns variables or returns a result set, but not both.

These are incompatible:

```
SELECT  @theSum,
        @M3   = case . . .
```

Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT @M3 = case . . . ;

SELECT @theSum, @M3;
```

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there any way in which I can re-write this line: `when @M1+@M2+@M4+@M5+@M6+@M7+@M8+@M9+@M10+@M11+@M12 != 0 then @M3-@M2`

Comment: @CM2K . . . Just use `when @theSum <> 0 then @M3 - @M2`.  You set `@theSum` before the `select`, so it is fine to use it.