# How to store value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Guests_Load
    @Id AS Varchar(30)  
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT *
    FROM Guests
    WHERE HotelId = @Id

    SELECT 
        GroupId,
        HotelName,
    FROM 
        HotelView(NOLOCK)   
    WHERE 
        HotelId = @Id
GO
```

Now, I want to create a new result set by writing another `SELECT` statement.

However, I want the `groupId` that is returned from the second `SELECT`. How do I do this? I tried:

```
DECLARE @hotelId int;

SELECT 
    @hotelId = GroupId,
    HotelName,
FROM 
    HotelView(NOLOCK)   
WHERE 
    HotelId = @Id
```

but I get an error saying

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608140/a-select-statement-that-assigns-a-value-to-a-variable-must-not-be-combined-with)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is just to run the query twice:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Guests_Load (
    @Id AS Varchar(30) 
) AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM Guests
    WHERE HotelId = @Id;

    SELECT GroupId, HotelName
    FROM HotelView 
    WHERE HotelId = @Id;

    DECLARE @GroupId int;

    SELECT @GroupId = GroupId
    FROM HotelView
    WHERE HotelId = @Id;

END;
```

Personally, I am not a fan of stored procedures printing out tables.  So, I would be inclined to have all the `SELECT`s use only variables. But if you want the print-out, then one method is to run the code twice.